# Laravel - How to update checkbox field value

Tags: laravel

Using Laravel-5.8, I have been able to save the data into the database including the check box field.

```
protected $fillable = [
    'appraisal_name',
    'is_current',
    'appraisal_start',
    'appraisal_end',
];
```

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'appraisal_name'  => 'required|min:5|max:100',
        'appraisal_start' => 'required',
        'appraisal_end'   => 'required|after_or_equal:appraisal_start',
        'is_current'      => 'nullable|boolean',
    ];
}
```

```
public function create()
{
    return view('appraisal.appraisal_identities.create');
}

public function store(StoreAppraisalIdentityRequest $request)
{
    $identity = AppraisalIdentity::create([
        'appraisal_name'  => $request->appraisal_name,
        'appraisal_start' => $appraisalStart,
        'appraisal_end'   => $appraisalEnd,
        'is_current'      => $request->has('is_current'),
    ]);
    Session::flash('success', 'Appraisal Initialization is created successfully');

    return redirect()->route('appraisal.appraisal_identities.index');
}

public function edit($id)
{
    abort_unless(\Gate::allows('appraisal_identity_edit'), 403);
    $identity = AppraisalIdentity::where('id', $id)->first();

    return view('appraisal.appraisal_identities.edit')->with('identity', $identity);
}

public function update(UpdateAppraisalIdentityRequest $request, $id)
{
    abort_unless(\Gate::allows('appraisal_identity_edit'), 403);

    $appraisalStart = Carbon::parse($request->appraisal_start);
    $appraisalEnd = Carbon::parse($request->appraisal_end);
    $submissionStart = Carbon::parse($request->submission_start);
    $submissionEnd = Carbon::parse($request->submission_end);

    $identity = AppraisalIdentity::find($id);
    $identity->appraisal_name = $request->appraisal_name;
    $identity->appraisal_start = $appraisalStart;
    $identity->appraisal_end = $appraisalEnd;
    $identity->is_current = $request->has('is_current');
    $identity->save();
    Session::flash('success', 'Appraisal Initialization is updated successfully');

    return redirect()->route('appraisal.appraisal_identities.index');
}
```

**create.blade**

```html
<form  action="{{route('appraisal.appraisal_identities.store')}}" method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <div class="form-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group row">
                     <label class="control-label text-right col-md-3">Is Current Appraisal?</label>
                      <div class="col-md-9">
                          <input type="checkbox" class="form-control"  name="is_current" value="{{old('is_current')}}">
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div>
          <!--<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="{{ trans('global.save') }}">-->
          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">{{ trans('global.save') }}</button>
          <button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='{{route('appraisal.appraisal_identities.index')}}'" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
      </div>
</form>
```

edit.blade

```html
 <form  action="{{route('appraisal.appraisal_identities.update', ['id'=>$identity->id])}}" method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT">
    <div class="form-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group row">
                     <label class="control-label text-right col-md-3">Is Current Appraisal?</label>
                      <div class="col-md-9">
                          <input type="checkbox" class="form-control"  name="is_current" value="{{old('is_current')}}">
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div>
          <!--<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="{{ trans('global.save') }}">-->
          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">{{ trans('global.save') }}</button>
          <button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='{{route('appraisal.appraisal_identities.index')}}'" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
      </div>
</form>
```

I have these issues while trying to update the data?

1. The edit checkbox field (is_current) did not pick the value from the database when loaded. It remains unchecked.
2. is_current is either 0 or 1. The goal is that, there can only be one is_current field that is set to 1 in the table. From the checkbox, when is_current is checked to 1, it should set any other is_current that is 1 to 0 in the table.

How do I resolve these issues?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In edit blade update your checkbox code as this:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="form-control"  name="is_current" @if($identity->is_current == 1) checked @endif value="{{old('is_current')}}">
```

In your update function change this:

```
public function update(UpdateAppraisalIdentityRequest $request, $id)
{
    abort_unless(\Gate::allows('appraisal_identity_edit'), 403);

    $appraisalStart = Carbon::parse($request->appraisal_start);
    $appraisalEnd = Carbon::parse($request->appraisal_end);
    $submissionStart = Carbon::parse($request->submission_start);
    $submissionEnd = Carbon::parse($request->submission_end);

    $identity = AppraisalIdentity::find($id);
    $identity->appraisal_name = $request->appraisal_name;
    $identity->appraisal_start = $appraisalStart;
    $identity->appraisal_end = $appraisalEnd;
    $identity->is_current = $request->has('is_current');
    $identity->save();

    // this line update all column to 0 and leave $id field
    AppraisalIdentity::where('id', '!=', $id)->update(['is_current' => 0]);

    Session::flash('success', 'Appraisal Initialization is updated successfully');

    return redirect()->route('appraisal.appraisal_identities.index');
}
```

In your store function change this:

```
public function store(StoreAppraisalIdentityRequest $request)
{
    $identity = AppraisalIdentity::create([
        'appraisal_name'  => $request->appraisal_name,
        'appraisal_start' => $appraisalStart,
        'appraisal_end'   => $appraisalEnd,
        'is_current'      => $request->has('is_current'),
    ]);


    $id = $identity->id;
    // this line update all column to 0 and leave $id field
    AppraisalIdentity::where('id', '!=', $id)->update(['is_current' => 0]);

    Session::flash('success', 'Appraisal Initialization is created successfully');

    return redirect()->route('appraisal.appraisal_identities.index');
}
```

Comment: Ankur Mishra, you've helped me resolved the first problem. The second one is still there. Thanks

Comment: @mikefolu Pls check the updated answer for making other 1 to 0 in table.

Comment: @mikefolu if your column is enum('0', '1'), then add this line ['is_current' => '0']

Comment: Ankur Mishra, the method (AppraisalIdentity::where('id', '!=', $id)->update(['is_current' => 0])) only work in update action. When I tried to apply it to create(store) action of the controller, I got this error:  Undefined variable: id

Comment: @mikefolu this is due to id variable is not exist in store function.

Comment: @mikefolu pls check store function now.

Answer (score 0):

try this in the edit blade 
<
is_current == 1 ? checked : value="{{old('is_current')}}">